# How would I make a transaction to buy a physical product using the Stellar Network?

Tags: transactions, xlm, purchasing, protocol

My understanding of the SCP is that when a trade happens it must hold the same value across the network. If a transaction happens that is not a 1 to 1 exchange and is validated by a node it is technically a befowled node. Would there be a way other then using an authorization revokable coin to make this physical transaction work?

Answer (score 7):

Stellar transactions are non-reversible. A solution to prevent fraud when buying a physical product is to use [multi-signature](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html) and have both the buyer and the seller agree on an impartial mediator. The principle is the same as [Bitcoin 2-of-3 multisig transactions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13854/68803).

The developer documentation has an example on [how to set up a multisig accounts](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#multi-signature-account) on the Stellar network

Comment: So I would create a payments transaction and only allow it to be signed when I receive the goods. Would I possibly be able to do this with a fiat to XLM to fiat pairing or is it only plausible XLM to XLM?

Comment: Stellar transactions are non-reversible - Authorization revocable (0x2): Allows the issuing account to revoke its credit held by other accounts. I believe that this is a flag that allows me to revoke a coin.